# algorithm to find how many radar towers can be turned on without interference

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, graph-theory, puzzle

I thought of an interesting problem and was wondering if anyone knows how to solve it:

> On earth there are many cities. Bob built a radar tower in each city.
>   Each city was supposed to be able to play its local music.
>
> Unforgivably, all the radar towers interfere with each other, so Bob
>   had to turn them all off.
>
> Luckily bob invented shields which he placed between cities (some were
>   placed near the core of the earth, some were placed on city borders).
>
> For the N cities, there are N*(N-1)/2 shields.
>
> Regrettably, Many shields were destroyed.
>
> You are given the pairs of cities that have no shield between them.

The task is to **find the maximum number of radar towers that can be turned on without causing any interference**.

So far I have tried representing this as a graph (cities are connected if there is no shield between them), and finding a coloring of the graph which maximizes the number of the most common color. Basically I select a start node, make it red, then all surrounding nodes go to blue, then red, etc. I was wondering if there is a faster way.

Comment: I added my research effort thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this a question about a maximum independent set as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29#Finding_maximum_independent_sets ? (NP-complete, but with an exponential-time algorithm faster that naive brute force search)

Comment: Ah right, so if I take the complement of my graph, I then need to find the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem maximum clique.

Answer (score 1):

Two radar towers cannot be turned on at the same time if they are in the supplied pairs where there is no shield between them. By finding the longest depth of a tree where a node indicates a radar tower turned on you can find the maximum number of towers which can be turned on without interference by taking the branch which has the longest depth. Once you take a node (i.e. Turn a tower on) you have to disable all other towers which don't have shields with that tower.